# Proper approach to create DispalyAds campaign - one-to-one or all-to-all variants?

Tags: advertising, marketing, sem, facebook-ads-manager

I'm about to create a campaign on Facebook. I'm wondering if it will benefit from creating multiple ad variants. For example I have Red, Green and Blue variant and two texts (T1, T2) and two headers (H1, H2).

Will I benefit from putting more work into campaign to create multiple ads or would it be better to keep it simple?

##### Simple one to one

- Red H1 T1
- Blue H2 T2
- Red H3 T3

##### Complex all to all

- Red H1 T1
- Red H1 T2
- Red H2 T1
- Red H2 T2
- Green H1 T1
- *etc...*

Comment: Social media search engines very much enjoy 'likes'. They are _(in the first place)_ the reason that we are able to target so effectively on social media. I would focus on whichever encourages the most of those.

Comment: So, theoretically you're saing to use as many variants as possible. But, on the other hand. Likes will be split i think. Each add gets its own Like pool if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe are two of the best approaches to testing by far. Ultimately, testing is truly the most important part. Let the data decide!

### The Type of Ad Matters

For *Static Ads*: **Simple One to One** - I would test this first.

If *Carousel Ads*: **Complex All to All**

In either configuration, when it's clear which is the winner, expand out that design. **You'll absolutely benefit from the extra work of creating as many variants as possible.**

Regardless of approach, if your target audience and region/geo are not configured very granularly, neither will perform very well, so make sure you nail that too.

***Additional Note:***

Carousels tend to enjoy higher engagement. Especially for professional services such as finance, or local service providers. This is primarily because, 5 images (carousel) beats 3 images (static).

---

### More Likes = More Reach

Hypothetically, say Jane has a promoted facebook post or ad (known to behave slightly different) - so consider John and Lisa get Janes post in their feeds and both like it but don’t convert.

FB will take our demographics and interests, cross reference that against those who *did* convert for similarities, and then try to reach more people that might also like Janes Ad or sponsored post.